# Windows Server 2016 datetime switching between two values repeatedly

Tags: time, windows-server

I have a Windows 2016 Standard server, whose time seems to oscillate between two values every second or two. It would suggest to me that two different things are repeatedly trying to reset the time.

I've run:

```
w32tm /resync 
net time \\DC /set
```

which sets it to today's date (in the tray), which is currently 17/12/2021 11:35, but after a couple of seconds it then switches to 14/12/2021 22:09, and then a couple of seconds later changes back again. It's a SQL server so this is causing some interesting issues, although it's a dev box, not live.

How can I tell what else is setting the datetime, or, failing that what other pieces of software/services might be doing so?

If I run `w32tm /query /source`, I get:

`Free-running system clock`

And if I run `w32tm /query /configuration`, I get:

```
EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Local)
Type: AllSync (Local)
NtpServer: time.windows.com,0x8 (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

Following @harrymc 's comments below, looking at the eventvwr for event ID 4616 (the system time was changed), there are two processes modifying the system time. I've looked them up in the task managed, tab Services:

```
PID: 0x394 => 916 (correct time)
Group: LocalServiceNetworkRestricted
vmictimesync
TimeBrokerSvc
Imhosts
EventLog
Dhcp
```

```
PID: 0x3a8 => 936 (incorrect time)
Group: Local Service
WinHttpAutoProxySvc
W32Time *-> Windows Time Service?*
nsi
netprofm
FontCache
EventSystem
CDPSvc
```

Stopping the `Windows Time service` leaves the time at the correct value, so this is a fix, although why it's trying to set it to a time that is 3 days old, I'm rather confused by. I'll leave the service switched off for the moment.

There is possibly another fix through Akina's comments below by removing time.windows.com as a time server. If I find a fix this way, I'll augment this post. Thanks to both @harrymc and @akina.

Comment: Check that there is only one stratum server in the list.

Comment: @Akina - sorry to sound stupid, but, which list where? And what is a stratum server?

Comment: Stratum server is NTP server which provides accurate time. Check `w32tm /query /source`

Comment: Thanks @Akina. I've added additional information above. Note that the computer doesn't have access to the internet.

Comment: If your server have no access to Internet then `NtpServer: time.windows.com` is obviously wrong. Either select some accessible NTP server in your LAN (for example, some commutators may provide this service, or you may set some server to be primary time server your LAN) or make this server primary NTP in your LAN (and sync all another NTP clients with it). I.e. in the LAN there must be only one primary NTP, and all clients must sync their time with it. Read more about NTP.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. This is a bit new to me.

Comment: @MarkRoworth - You should your question to indicate the box has no Internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find which process changed the date/time, consult
[Event ID 4616 : The system time was changed](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4616):

- Run the Event Viewer
- Position to *Windows Logs > Security*
- Right-click Security and select "Filter Current Log..."
- In the dialog Filter Current Log, Filter tab, enter the
  `Event ID 4616`
- Click OK

In the displayed events list, click on an event to see its details,
and especially under "Process Information" see
the "Name" field.

Comment: thanks v much. This has pointed me in a direction which means I can solve the issue for the moment. I've added details above. I'm going to mark this as a solution, as it has directly led to me stopping the behaviour, although I think Akina's approach would also lead there.